# Функция vba на c#

Tags: c#, vba

Подскажите, как написать такую же функцию на c#

```
Sub copyTable()
Dim colRange(), destColRange()
Dim Text As String
Dim i As Long, newI As Long, n As Long, j As Long
Dim maxLen As Long
colRange = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) 'Columns where your data is'
destColRange = Array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17) 'Columns where you want
'data be copied'
n = UBound(colRange) - LBound(colRange)-1
i = 2 'Initial row'
newI = i
maxLen = 500 'Maximum size allowed in one cell'

While Not (Cells(i, colRange(0)) Is Nothing) And (Cells(i, colRange(0)) <> 
"")
    Text = Cells(i, colRange(n))

    Do
        For j = 0 To n - 1
            Cells(newI, destColRange(j)) = Cells(i, colRange(j))
        Next j

        Cells(newI, destColRange(j)) = Mid(Text, 1, maxLen)
        Text = Mid(Text, maxLen + 1)
        newI = newI + 1
    Loop Until Len(Text) <= 0

    i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

(Поправил в коде некоторый вещи, то что мне нужно было)
Вот примерно, что делает макрос.
[image: макрос]

Вот попробовал сделать так, но не получается.

```
static class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        // тестовые данные
        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application() { Visible = true };
        Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Add();
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[1];
        Excel.Range table = sheet.Range["a1:d4"];

        table.Value = new object[,]
        {
            { "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4" },
            { 11, 12, "abcdefgh", 14 },
            { 21, 22, "abcd", 24 },
            { 31, 32, "ab", 34 },
        };

        table.Copy(sheet.Range["f1"]);
        table = sheet.Range["f1"].Resize[table.Rows.Count, table.Columns.Count];

        // как-то получаем диапазон таблицы (после копирования или еще откуда-
    то)
        // и "вытягиваем" его по второму столбцу (нумерация с нуля)
        // чтобы в нем было максимум по 3 символа
        WrapRows(table, 2, 3);
    }

    static void WrapRows(Excel.Range table, int Column, int MaxLength)
    {
        object[,] oldValue = table.Value; // Получаем данные из Excel в виде 
    массива
        object[,] newValue = oldValue
            .EnumerateRows() // Перечисляем строки
            .SelectMany(row => WrapRow(row, Column, MaxLength)) // каждую строку 
     рвем по столбцу
            .ToArray() // собираем в jagged массив
            .ToSolidArray(); // собираем в двумерный массив

        // переносим новые данные на лист
        table
            .Cells[1, 1] // берем первую ячейку
            // И растягиваем диапазон под размер новых данных
            .Resize[newValue.GetLength(0), newValue.GetLength(1)]
            .value = newValue; 
    }

    // берет строку (в виде массива) и делит её на несколько строк разрезанных 
    по столбцу
    static IEnumerable<object[]> WrapRow(object[] Row, int Column, int 
    MaxLength)
    {
        var text = Row[Column].ToString(); // исходная строка из ячейки
        do
        {
            var m = Math.Min(text.Length, MaxLength);
            var currentRow = Row.ToArray(); // копируем строку
            currentRow[Column] = text.Substring(0, m); // вставляем часть текста
            text = text.Substring(m); // удаляем вставленую часть текста 

            yield return currentRow;
        }
        while (text.Length > 0);
    }

    // Берет двумерный массив и пересичляет его строки как отдельные массивы
    static IEnumerable<T[]> EnumerateRows<T>(this T[,] solid)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < solid.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            var row = new T[solid.GetLength(1)];
            for (int j = 0; j < row.Length; j++)
                row[j] = solid[solid.GetLowerBound(0) + i, 
    solid.GetLowerBound(1) + j];

            yield return row;
        }
    }

    // Преобразует рванный массив в двумерный
    static T[,] ToSolidArray<T>(this T[][] jagged)
    {
        var solid = new T[jagged.Length, jagged[0].Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < solid.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < solid.GetLength(1); j++)
                solid[i, j] = jagged[i][j];

        return solid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавил код. То что пробовал сделать, но должным образом не получилось реализовать этот макрос. По этому решил задать вопрос тут. Быть может у кого нибудь был похожий макрос по функционалу.

Comment: Ок, уже лучше, теперь осталось дописать, что именно не получается, какой результат необходимо получить. Вечером могу посмотреть код подробно, но не хочу по коду угадывать исходную задачу, при условии что и код на VBA может содержать ошибки

Comment: Код на vba работает. Когда в ячейке 7 столбца(начало считывания со 2 строки) символов больше чем 500, перенести остальные символы в строку ниже и продублировать текст из ячеек в столбцах 1-6. Правда хотелось бы, что бы еще можно было выбрать от какого столбца все зависело. (но это уже потом) В своем коде я делал по 3 столбцам.

Comment: "Когда в ячейке 7 столбца" переделал немного кода на vba теперь от 6 все зависит и можно выбирать столбец.